# Migrate S3 images to use CDN

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, cloudinary

I have an app which currently using S3 to store images, and it took a lot of time to load images in my mobile app.

Now I'm looking for a better way to optimize the loading time. One possible solution I came up with is to load images through a CDN (Cloudinary, Cloudfront, ...). However I'm currently storing images  with S3 urls in my database. How can I migrate it to use a CDN url, not the S3 one? Is there any better way than updating all the image url in my database?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using S3 + Cloudfront, I think you should look up to this blogpost https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/

[Infrastructure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1JO.png)

usually what I do is store in my database only the path, then the web application can compose the url on its own. Or else you can inject the cloudfront url for each image directly from your backend.

The blogpost also has a CloudFormation stack you can use to deploy everything as code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in using Cloudinary, you can still use your own S3 and just use Cloudinary for optimization and delivery. Cloudinary is a multi-CDN network and will handle spikes in traffic, caching and delivery on a global scale. There can be a lot of headaches you can just avoid.

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520492-Can-images-be-stored-in-my-own-S3-bucket-